# CSS 'schema' how-to

Tags: css, styling

How does one go about establishing a CSS 'schema', or hierarchy, of general element styles, nested element styles, and classed element styles.  For a rank novice like me, the amount of information in stylesheets I view is completely overwhelming.  What process does one follow in creating a well factored stylesheet or sheets, compared to inline style attributes?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72911/whats-the-best-way-to-organize-css-rules

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm a big fan of naming my CSS classes by their contents or content types, for example a <ul> containing navigational "tabs" would have class="tabs". A header containing a date could be class="date" or an ordered list containing a top 10 list could have class="chart". Similarly, for IDs, one could give the page footer id="footer" or the logo of the website id="mainLogo". I find that it not only makes classes easy to remember but also encourages proper cascading of the CSS. Things like ol.chart {font-weight: bold; color: blue;} #footer ol.chart {color: green;} are quite readable and takes into account how CSS selectors gain weight by being more specific.

Proper indenting is also a great help. Your CSS is likely to grow quite a lot unless you want to refactor your HTML templates evertime you add a new section to your site or want to publish a new type of content. However hard you try you will inevitably have to add a few new rules (or exceptions) that you didn't anticipate in your original schema. Indeting will allow you to scan a large CSS file a lot quicker. My personal preference is to indent on how specific and/or nested the selector is, something like this:

```
    ul.tabs {
    list-style-type: none;
    }
        ul.tabs li {
        float: left;
        }
            ul.tabs li img {
            border: none;
            }
```

That way the "parent" is always furthest to the left and so the text gets broken up into blocks by parent containers. I also like to split the stylesheet into a few sections; first comes all the selectors for HTML elements. I consider these so generic that they should come first really. Here I put "body { font-size: 77%; }" and "a { color: #FFCC00; }" etc. After that I would put selectors for the main framework parts of the page, for instance "ul#mainMenu { float: left; }" and "div#footer { height: 4em; }". Then on to common object classes, "td.price { text-align: right; }", finally followed by extra little bits like ".clear { clear: both; }". Now that's just how I like to do it - I'm sure there are better ways but it works for me.

Finally, a couple of tips:

1. Make best use of cascades and don't "overclass" stuff. If you give a <ul> class="textNav" then you can access its <li>s and their children without having to add any additional class assignments. ul.textNav li a:hover {}
2. Don't be afraid to use multiple classes on a single object. This is perfectly valid and very useful. You then have control of the CSS for groups of objects from more than one axis. Also giving the object an ID adds yet a third axis. For example:

   ```
   <style>
   div.box {
   float: left;
   border: 1px solid blue;
   padding: 1em;
   }

   div.wide {
   width: 15em; 
   }

   div.narrow {
   width: 8em; 
   }

   div#oddOneOut {
   float: right;
   }
   </style>

   <div class="box wide">a wide box</div>
   <div class="box narrow">a narrow box</div>
   <div class="box wide" id="oddOneOut">an odd box</div>
   ```
3. Giving a class to your document <body> tag (or ID since there should only ever be one...) enables some nifty overrides for individual pages, like hilighting the menu item for the page you're currently on or getting rid of that redundant second sign-in form on the sign-in page, all using CSS only. "body.signIn div#mainMenu form.signIn { display: none; }"

I hope you find at least some of my ramblings useful and wish you the best with your projects!

Comment: Are you kidding me? Most developers can indent correctly and you definitely should indent the properties in the selector (so you use 4 spaces before `float: left` etc.

Comment: No joke. CSS is not white space sensitive. Nor does the spec say anything about indentation. And I'm a stickler for formatting and standards. Not indenting the declarations is a personal choice; if you don't like it go ahead and indent them! I see a lot of people putting short (and sometimes not so short!) CSS blocks on a single line which I find annoying, though I sometimes do this in JS. Oh and I indent my CSS (and JS, and HTML) files with tabs, not spaces. Scream all you like.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of different things you can do to aid in the organisation of your CSS.  For example:

- Split your CSS up into multiple files.  For example: have one file for layout, one for text, one for reset styles etc.
- Comment your CSS code.
- Why not add a table of contents?
- Try using a CSS framework like [960.gs](http://960.gs) to get your started.

It's all down to personal taste really.  But here are a few links that you might find useful:

- http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/08/18/7-principles-of-clean-and-optimized-css-code/
- http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/05/02/improving-code-readability-with-css-styleguides/
- http://www.louddog.com/bloggity/2008/03/css-best-practices.php
- http://natbat.net/2008/Sep/28/css-systems/

Answer (score 3):

Think of the CSS as creating a 'toolkit' that the HTML can refer to. The following rules will help:

- Make `class` names unambiguous. In most cases this means prefixing them in a predicatable way. For example, rather than `left`, use something like `header_links_object2_left`.
- Use `id` rather than `class` **only** if you know there will only **ever** be one of an object on a page. Again, make the `id` unambiguous.
- Consider side effects. Rules like `margin` and `padding`, `float` and `clear`, and so on can all have unexpected consequences on other elements.
- If your stylesheet is to be used my several HTML coders, consider writing them a small, clear guide to how to write HTML to match your scheme. Keep it simple, or you'll bore them.

And as always, test it in multiple browsers, on multiple operating systems, on lots of different pages, and under any other unusual conditions you can think of.

Comment: I don't think using a style dependant name (i.e. calling styles "head_links_left") is a good idea.  What if you decide to move the links in the left to the right ?  You should change the style name !  That's not easy to mantain.  I prefer to use "semantic" names, for example just "head_links".

Answer (score 2):

Putting all of your CSS declarations in roughly the same order as they will land in the document hierarchy is generally a good thing. This makes it fairly easy for future readers to see what attributes will be inherited, since those classes will be higher up in the file.

Also, this is sort of orthogonal to your question, but if you are looking for a tool to help you read a CSS file and see how everything shakes out, I cannot recommend [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) enough.

Comment: I love FireBug's Inspect Element.  In fact I love all of FireBug.

Answer (score 2):

The best organizational advice I've ever received came from a presentation at An Event Apart.

Assuming you're keeping everything in a single stylesheet, there's basically five parts to it:

1. Reset rules (may be as simple as the
   `* {margin: 0; padding: 0}` rule,
   Eric Meyer's reset, or the YUI
   reset)
2. Basic element styling; this
   is the stuff like basic typography
   for paragraphs, spacing for lists,
   etc.
3. Universal classes; this section
   for me generally contains things
   like `.error`, `.left` (I'm only 80%
   semantic), etc.
4. Universal
   layout/IDs; `#content`, `#header`,
   or whatever you've cut your page up
   into.
5. Page-specific rules; if you
   need to modify an existing style
   just for one or a few pages, stick a
   unique ID high up (body tag is
   usually good) and toss your
   overrides at the end of the document

I don't recommend using a CSS framework unless you need to mock something up in HTML *fast*.  They're far too bloated, and I've never met one whose semantics made sense to me; it's much better practice to create your own "framework" as you figure out what code is shared by your projects over time.

Reading other people's code is a whole other issue, and with that I wish you the best of luck.  There's some truly horrific CSS out there.

Answer (score 1):

Cop-out line of the year: it depends.

How much do you need to be styling? Do you need to change the aspects of alomost every element, or is it only a few?

My favorite place to go for information like this is [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/) & [A List Apart](http://alistapart.com/).

Answer (score 1):

There are two worlds:

1. `The human editor perspective:` Where CSS is most easily understand, when it has clear structure, good formatting, verbose names, structured into layout, color and typesetting...
2. `The consumer perspective:` The visitor is most happy if your site loades quickly, if it look perfect in his browser, so the css has to be small, in one file (to save further connections) and contain CSS hacks to support all browsers.

I recommend you to start with a [CSS framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_framework):

- [Blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) if you like smaller things
- or [YAML](http://www.yaml.de/en/) for a big and functional one

There is also a [list of CSS Frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CSS_frameworks)...

And then bring it in shape (for the browser) with a [CSS Optimizer](http://www.google.ch/search?q=css+optimizer) (p.e. [CSS Form.&Opti.](http://floele.flyspray.org/csstidy//css_optimiser.php))

You can measure the Results (unpotimized <-> optimized) with [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/).

Answer (score 1):

A few more tips for keeping organized:

- Within each declaration, adopt an order of attributes that you stick to. For example, I usually list margins, padding, height, width, border, fonts, display/float/other, in that order, allowing for easier readability in my next tip
- Write your CSS like you would any other code: indent! It's easy to scan a CSS file for high level elements and then drill down rather than simply going by source order of your HTML.
- Semantic HTML with good class names can help a lot with remembering what styles apply to which elements.